# Create GCS bucket with versioning

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create GCS bucket with versioning.

I created sub-module.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage" {
    project = "${var.project}"
    name = "${var.storage_name}"
    location = "${var.location}"
    storage_class = "${var.storage_class}"
    versioning = "${var.versioning}"
}
```

As per Terraform [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html#versioning), I can pass versioning arguments to configure versioning.

I don't know what kind of data **versioning** argument accepts. I tried passing bool (true), map and list as follow.

**map**

```
variable "versioning" {
  type = list
  default = {
    generation = true,
    metageneration = true
  }
}
```

**List**

```
variable "versioning" {
  type = list
  default = [
    "generation",
    "metageneration"
  ]
  description = "Enable versioning on Bucket"
}
```

I tried this after reading [this GCP Doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#details)

---

**Error**
error I am getting it as below.

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on ../modules/storage/main.tf line 6, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "cloud_storage":
   6:     versioning = "${var.versioning}"

An argument named "versioning" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a
block of type "versioning"?
```

The module works fine, if I don't use versioning arguments. But, I want to create module which can configure versioning too.

Please let me know if I am going in wrong direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `metageneration` come from? You should have a block of `versioning = { "enabled"  = true }` and that's all.

Comment: I was reading [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#details) and guessed the value of versioning. Thank you for the help. It works with the block of versioning { enabled = true}.

Comment: Use the Terraform docs to work out what parameters you should be using, not the underlying API docs.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is indicating that the **versioning** argument is a block (not a map), thus including the '=' confuses Terraform.

Use:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "foo" {
    ...
    versioning {
      enabled = true
    }
}
```

NOT

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "foo" {
    ...
    versioning = {
      enabled = true
    }
}
```